# How to set class="active" in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<div class="box">
        <div id="banks">
            <ul>
                <li class="active1">Bank1</li>
                <li">Bank2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li class="active2">USD</li>
                <li>EURO</li>
            </ul>        
        </div>
</div>
```

And jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box li').click(function(){
        $('#banks li').removeClass('active1');
        $('#buttons li').removeClass('active2');
        $(this).addClass('active1');
        $(this).addClass('active2');
    });    
});
</script>
```

OUPUT: Error when click on:

```
<div class="box">
        <div id="banks">
            <ul>
                <li class="active2 active1">Bank1</li>
                <li class="active2">Bank2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li class="">USD</li>
                <li class="">EURO</li>
            </ul>        
        </div>
</div>
```

How to using jquery exactly for add class for 2 id are (banks and buttons) with 2 class are (active1, active2)

Comment: Do you want to make active Bank2 and EURO both active after clicking one of them?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen when you click?  There is no error here - the behavior is just a little strange.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/dzXYU/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AS I understand you need to be able to choise single option in each section. Use only one `active` class and change styles in css:

html:

```
<div class="box">
        <div id="banks">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">Bank1</li>
                <li>Bank2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">USD</li>
                <li>EURO</li>
            </ul>        
        </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box li').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

css:

```
.box li { cursor:pointer; }
#banks .active { color:red; }
#buttons .active { color:blue; }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/jn3v4/2/

Comment: You can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead of `.parent().find('li')`.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".active-class a").click(function() {
  $(".active-class a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
a.active
{
background:#000000;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
            <ul>
                <li class="active-class"><a href="#" class="active">home</a></li>
                <li class="active-class"><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li class="active-class"><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
                <li class="active-class"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: crispy & super clean!

Answer (score 1):

when removing the class you are looking only inside the `#box` change it to `.box` like

```
$('.box li').click(function(){
    $('.box li').removeClass('active1');
    $('.box li').removeClass('active2');
    $(this).addClass('active1');
    $(this).addClass('active2');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3LePK/18/)**

Answer (score 0):

Jquery function:

```
(".box li").click(function() {
  $(".box li").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```